# Update array with elements from another array react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my array with elements from another array using useState Hook. Is there anyway to do it? thanks
code --->

```
function App() {

  const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(numbers)
    nums.forEach(num => {
      numbers.push(num);
    })
    setNumbers(numbers)
    console.log(numbers)
  }, [])


  return (
    <>
      {numbers.length && numbers.map(num => 
        <p key={Math.random() * 10000}>{num}</p>  
      )}
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I think you are trying to set `nums` in `numbers`. That can be easily done with `const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(nums)`. I just initialized `numbers` with `nums`. You don't event need a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you mean is, you want to make a copy of that array, as your own data, so you can just do:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setNumbers([...nums]);
  }, []);
```

or you can even do

```js
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([...nums]);
```

without the `useEffect()`.

You can use

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(nums);
```

but just note that `numbers` and `nums` refer to the same array object this way.

By the way, using a random number as the `key` defeats the purpose of it... but you may already know that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to set `nums` in numbers. That can be easily done with `const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(nums)`. I just initialized numbers with `nums`. You don't event need a `useEffect`.

If you really want to experiment with `useEffect` then don't mutate the data with `push`. You can use `filter`, `map` and `reduce` to deal with arrays to avoid mutation. Or just use the spread syntax like another answer posted.

`setNumbers([...nums]);`

Comment: Spread syntax works perfectly..but I actually need to use useEffect as I'm fetching data from an api. And that's an array of objects..and I want to update my state with an array containing the objects.....

Comment: this is the actual code
```
useEffect(() => {
    let getProducts: () => Promise<void>
    getProducts = async () => {
      const res = await commerce.products.list();
      res.data.forEach((product) => {
        products.push(
          {
            name: product.name, 
            description: product.description, 
            price: product.price.formatted_with_symbol, 
            id: product.id,
            imgURL: product.media.source
          }
        )
      })
      setProducts([...products]);
    }
    getProducts(); 
  }, [])
```